# Are there power socket adapters from H to E/F which carry grounding?

Tags: europe, israel, electrical-goods

Israel has - unfortunately -  a unique plug type, Type H:

[image]

and I'm interested in using some German or Dutch equipment / cables with it. This is trivial to do if you forego grounding, as Type-H sockets take type-C and type-E/F plugs with no adaptation needed. But I do want that grounding.

Now, you *can* get a socket adapter, which on the male side has the third pin:

[image]

and thus, hopefully, it carries the grounding (though who knows, right?). However, grounding can only be carried on condition of your plug passing the grounding using a third pin that goes into the adapter: Types B, G, H, I, K, L etc. The popular EU plugs, type F (and type E) either take a reverse-pin for the grounding:

[image]

or touch grounding on the rim of the socket:

[image]

and I have not been able to find adapter which have any of these two features. Do such plugs exist at all? If not, are there other solutions for hooking up EU electrical equipment with grounding, in Israel / Palestine?

Comment: Good question, but I'm not sure who to ask. Electronics might know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently purchased several from [Dinic](https://www.dinic-shop.de/strom/reiseadapter/adapter-fuer-israel/dinic-stromadapter-israel-auf-schuko-cee-7-3-buchse-3pin-stecker.html).

I've purchased from the same firm before for other adapters, so I have a small collection now, and they're all quite sturdy with excellent tolerances, and yes, grounded.

About 5€ each, before shipping; also on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/stores/page/E931784C-1429-4327-8872-8A75A2B2F86C)

Answer (score 3):

One option I'm trying to avoid, but which should work, is:

1. Take a type-F extension chord.
2. Cut the male side (i.e. the plug end of it). Tool: Heavy wire cutter.
3. Open up the cable somewhat. Tool: Utility knife.
4. Expose the 3 wires' copper. Tool: Careful work with a utility knife or wire exposre tool + pulling.
5. Buy a self-assembly Type-H plug at a hardware store (just about any store will have this). Here's how it typically looks like:

   [image]
6. Screw the plug open. Tool: Phillips screwdriver (of proper edge size)
7. Loosen the bottom pair of screws, to create more space underneath the plastic bar between them
8. Insert the 3 wires through the bottom and through the plastic bars.
9. Attach the wires at their correct positions in the plug-head (Neutral/Zero is left, Phase is right, grounding is down) - by loosening, inserting the wire then tightening.
10. Tighten the two bottom screws again.
11. Screw the plug closed.

This will work, but self-assembled plugs are typically less sturdy and more prone to burn out due to tugging etc.

Note: You'd better have both a relatively narrow Phillips screwdriver and a relatively narrow flat-head one. Don't ask me about exact widths.

Comment: The required screwdrivers will depend on the precise model of the screw-on plug( and you usually can't tell when you buy the plug in the hardware shop),

Comment: Adaptors are also rather unsturdy.  Screw-on plugs are not that dangerous.  When I was a child, appliances never came with a plug - you *always* had to buy one and fit it.  This is probably the most robust solution.

Comment: Final comments: 1. Depending on the thickness of the cord, you may need to completely remove the cable clamp (plastic bar) and reverse it.  2, It is *vitally* important the cable clamp clamps on to the *outer* insulation (and not the three wires).  3.  When removing the insulation from the wires, be careful not to nick the wire with the knife - this will dangerously weaken the cable.

Answer (score 1):

They certainly do exist, try googling "israel schuko adapter" for example. That gives me something like this [Skross 1.500216](https://www.conrad.com/ce/en/product/552398/Travel-adapter--------Combo-World-to-Israel----Skross----1500216) (just a random pick for illustration, no recommendation implied), which clearly has the two grounding spring contacts. You can probably find a cheaper non-universal alternative with a bit more googling.

Alternatively, what about replacing the entire power cord with a ready-made (moulded) Israeli one?

Comment: I have a bunch of F cords and power strips I brought back from the Netherlands, including one with some surge protection, so I wanted to use those with an Israeli socket instead of buying new ones. But 18 EUR + shipping is pricey... I'll try and search some more.

Comment: If you already *have* a power strip, replacing the plug on it is *definitely* the best option.